# Select Student list which is not in another table with date difference and aggregate function

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008, join

I have three table i.e. "tblStudents", "tblStudentFee", "tblTransaction". table design is

**tblStudents**

```
StudID
Name
FatherName
MobileNO
ClassID
```

**tblStudentFee**

```
StFeeID
StudID
SessionID
FeesID
FeeAmount
Discount
```

**tblTransaction**

```
TransactionID
StFeeID
StudID
TransDate
Amount
```

Now I want to join these table in a way that final table after join should have student fee data where tblTransaction.TransDate is 30 days old from today and I also want student who is not present in tblTransaction

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  We will not really do your homework for you, please add your attempts and what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT
tsf.* 
FROM tblStudentFee tsf
inner join tblStudents ts
 on tsf.StudID = ts.StudID
left join tblTransaction tt
 on tt.StudID = ts.StudID
  and tt.StFeeID = ts.StFeeID
where 
(
 tt.TransactionID is null
 or
 DATEDIFF(day,TransDate,getdate())=30
)
```